# In a non-relational DBMS (BigTable in AppEngine), how should I set up the entities for a mass messaging type-of system?

Tags: google-app-engine, performance, message, bigtable, non-relational-database

Imagine, for example that I have a lot of users. Every time a user messages something, he/she can message it to a list of other users (similar to mass-emailing). However, I just want to store the message once to save storage space. So, when one of the message receiver opens his mailbox, he/she must query for that message there. What's more efficient in terms of setting up the messaging system's entities (tables)? Note that: in an non-RDBMS, join queries are not allowed. So is this a plausible set up, and how can I make it more efficient (1):

```
Table: Message (keeps one copy of all messages)
| Message_ID | Sender | Title | Body | List of Receivers |

// In this strategy, if I'm a receiver, I would check each message and search through the list of receivers to check and see whether I'm one of the receivers or not.
```

Or should I go with the following strategy (2):

```
Table: Message (keeps one copy of all messages)
| Message_ID | Sender | Title | Body |

Table: Message Receivers (store the same message ID for all receivers)
| Message_ID | Sender | Receiver |

// In this strategy, in runtime, make copies of the same message ID and same Sender and store one row for each receiver.
```

Which strategy seems more efficient? i.e. is iterating through an arraylist slower than simply iterating through a DBMS?

Any comments would be highly appreciated.

*Note: messages can be arbitrarily long, hence I don't want to store multiple copies of the same message.

Thank you.

Comment: As if we don't have enough mass-mail. I hope for every copy of a message you send out, you also copy it to your own inbox :-)

Comment: I'm sure that OP's not talking about actual email. He's probably envisioning something more along the lines of Twitter.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't talking about mass email - I clearly stated in my post "SIMILAR to mass emailing". Thank you Adam for clarifying that, I was thinking of something along the lines of Twitter...

Answer (score 1):

Check out Brett Slatkin's ['Building Scalable, Complex Apps on App Engine'](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html) talk from Google IO 09.

He presents a pattern known as a 'RelationIndex', which is similar to your first suggestion but you move the list to its own entity.  By setting the list entity's key-name to the message's key-name, you can scan for messages to a user using a [keys_only query](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query),  then load only the message itself without the expense of deserializing the list of recipients.

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for that link. This is exactly what I was looking for! I guess I should start watching more Google IO talks - quite interesting! Thanks again.